# How to retrieve association data from string parameter value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a two models `User` and `Post` with `has_many` association. How to call all posts objects of particular user by using string object like `"posts"`. Here the issue is `"posts"` object coming in the form of string because am passing as argument. like below `@user."posts"`. can i have to convert string to any type?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-public_send) method

> Invokes the method identified by symbol, passing it any arguments
>   specified. Unlike send, #public_send calls public methods only. When
>   the method is identified by a string, the string is converted to a
>   symbol.

---

```
User.find(1).public_send('posts')
```

and with `params`

```
User.find(1).public_send(params[:name]) # replace name obviously with your query
```

---

**Update (security)**

@fanta made a very good observation in a comment regarding security with incoming params. If you have a sensitive app you should add some whitelisting to it

A basic version could be to only allow the `has_many` associations on your model.

```
# This will return all `has_many`s on your User model
@whitelist = User.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).map(&:name)

if @whitelist.include? params[:name]
  User.find(1).public_send(params[:name])
end
```